# Laravel: Can't delete record

Tags: php, laravel, sql-delete

I have customer table and I want to allow users to delete their account, but accounts can't be deleted, there are no relationship between `customer` table and `orders` table.

This is `customer` table indexes
[image: PHPMyAdmin foreign keys image]

This is the route:

```php
$router->get('/del/{phone}', 'UserController@del');
```

This is controller method:

```php
public function del($phone) {
    $user = User::where('phone', $phone)->first();

    if ($user->delete()) {
        return "ok";
    } else {
        return "not";
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> Internal Server Error

Comment: Use `dd($user);` to see errors

Comment: @user16806454 the user detail shown succesfully no errors

Comment: check laravel logs. You porbably have sql errors. Is Debug mode on?

Comment: @itachi I have this error : `syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in /home1/xxx/api.xxxxxx/vendor/psr/log/src/LoggerInterface.php on line 30` and `Exception thrown without a stack frame in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: what is your php version?

Comment: @itachi Php version is 8.1

Comment: @itachi in LoggerInterface.php file I deleted all | found then I get SQL error: ` Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`xxxxxxxxxxx`.`ordertbl`, CONSTRAINT `Customer_ordertbl` FOREIGN KEY (`cusID`) REFERENCES `customer` (`id`)) (SQL: delete from `customer` where `id` = 1175)`

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score -3):

in vendor/psr/log/src/LoggerInterface.php file I removed all | found in methods then it has been solved

Comment: Unless the offending pipe was put there manually (by accident) this suggests you aren’t running php 8. This seems unrelated/tangential to the asked question.

Comment: Making changes to code in `/vendor` is never a good idea. If you're using a Source Code Management system, like Git, `/vendor` is included in `.gitingore` for Laravel projects by default, meaning any changes you make to these files will not be saved/committed. Also, if you ever run `composer install`, or `composer update`, etc., you will lose these changes, or when deploying your code to a different environment, etc. You should try to solve your issue by updating your PHP version and dependencies properly.

Comment: This isn't a solution though. It's just a timebomb right now waiting to unleash a rain of errors in future.